# User environment variable in java

Tags: java, variables, environment-variables

I am trying to get a user environment variable in java.

The `System.getEnv()` method only return system environment variables.

Does anybody know how to get user environment variables?

Comment: [Try this once](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/env.html)

Comment: Yes I used System.getenv("myvariable") but it doesn't word. It only works for system variables, not user variables

Comment: Works just fine for me, its even case-insensitive. Note: On Windows 7.

Comment: Ok tks, I can't understand why it doesn't for me... My variable is named CODEAGENCE. In my programm `System.getenv("CODEAGENCE")` returns `null`. And for exemple `System.getenv("CLASSPATH")` returns the CLASSPATH correctly.

Comment: Have you tried restarting Windows? Also, when setting an environment variable you cannot necessarily reference other environment variables. How are you setting your variable?

Comment: Yes that is the answer, my windows session must be restarted !

Answer (score 12):

When running a process there is only one *environment*. The user variables are merged into the system variables, with overwriting existing ones. This complete environment is then retrieved by the `System.getenv()` method.

So you actually see the user's environment variables.

I just tested it with these four scenarios:

1) No variable named `MYVAR`:

Running `System.out.println(System.getenv("MYVAR"))` prints out `null`.

2) System variable called `MYVAR` with value `System`:

Running `System.out.println(System.getenv("MYVAR"))` prints out `System`.

3) User variable called `MYVAR` with value `User`:

Running `System.out.println(System.getenv("MYVAR"))` prints out `User`.

4) System variable called `MYVAR` with value `System` and user variable called `MYVAR` with value `User`:

Running `System.out.println(System.getenv("MYVAR"))` prints out `User`.

---

Maybe you did try it out from an IDE (like Eclipse)? When changing the environment variables, you unfortunately have to restart Eclipse, as they are not correctly propagated to the run configurations.

Answer (score 1):

[System.getenv(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getenv%28java.lang.String%29) is the correct method; there are only "environment variables" - Windows applies the "system" environment variables to everyone's account, but they aren't differentiable at the application level. You can verify by opening a `cmd` prompt and executing `set` (with no arguments).

Comment: In a command prompt, my variable is ok. A echo %myvariableM give me the good value. But the `System.getenv("myvariable")` give me a `null` value

Answer (score 0):

Seelenvirtuose is right. You need to write the name of the SYSTEM environment variable using quotes:

```java
String serverUrl = System.getenv("QNAP-NAS-ADDRESS");
private String jdbcURL = "jdbc:mysql://" + serverUrl + "schema_name?useSSL=false";
private String jdbcUsername = System.getenv("QNAP-MYSQL-UN");
private String jdbcPassword = System.getenv("QNAP-MYSQL-UN");
```

Printing these:

```java
System.out.println(System.getenv("QNAP-MYSQL-UN"));
System.out.println(System.getenv("QNAP-MYSQL-PW"));
System.out.println(System.getenv("QNAP-NAS-ADDRESS"));
System.out.println(System.getenv("QNAP-NOIP-ADDRESS"));
```

would display in terminal:

```
root
password
mynasserver.myqnapcloud.com
mynasserver.ddns.net
```

I didn't use *USER VARIABLES*, but **SYSTEM VARIABLES**.

@Seelenvirtuose Thanks, btw

Answer (score -2):

You can get the value of a USER environment variables, by reading the registry key in the path: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\Environment` There you will find all the USER environment variables added.

and for the SYSTEM environment variables you can read in the path: 
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Control\\Session Manager\\Environment`

Comment: Registry access is not a common practice and available to a java program.